# Threads to Generate, Convert and Count Frequency

Tags: java, multithreading

I'd like to create 3 threads: one to generate a random string, one to convert this string to lower case and one to count the frequency of the words in that string.

I've created `Generator`, `Convert` and `Freq` all of them with constructors like `(int[] buffer, Semaphore mutex, Semaphore items, Semaphore spc)`. I created a `Start` class:

```
public class Start
{
    static int first = 0;
    static ind last = 0;
}
```

with semaphores `mutex`, `items` and `spc`.

Here's the `run` method for my `Generator` class. It works fine and generate random upper case strings of length 15.

```
public void run()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int size = 15;

    while (true)
    {
        try 
        {
            char[] res = new char[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                res[i] = alphabet.charAt(rand.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
            }

            System.out.println("String generated: " + String.valueOf(res));

            spc.acquire();
            mutex.acquire();

            // buffer[Start.last] = res[0];
            Start.last = (Start.last + 1) % 100;

            mutex.release();
            items.release();

            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } 

        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I make `Convert` and `Freq` to read my array? I know how to convert to lower case (of course) and count the frequency of each letter in an array. I've created `run` methods for both classes with `items.acquire();` and `mutex.acquire()` but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for your time helping me ^^

Comment: you should keep that array as property of some object visible to all threads, not as local variable as you do now.

Answer (score 0):

When I understand you correctly, you want to run your `Generator` thread to generate strings, your `Convert` thread to convert the generated strings and your `Freq` thread to analyze the converted strings.

Since all three threads need to read results from other threads you should hold those data in a super-ordinate class/method. You could create three collections like `newStrings`, `convertedStrings` and `frequencies`. Your `Generator` thread creates strings and adds them to the `newStrings` collection. Your `Convert` thread looks into the `newStrings` collections and takes a new string from it (either by removing all old ones or counting the index), converts it and adds it to the `convertedStrings` collection. Your `Freq` thread then again takes a new converted String from the `convertedStrings` collection counts the frequencies of the words in this string and adds the result to the `frequencies` collection.